# antd: error TS2339: Property 'centered' does not exist on type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

```
<Modal visible={this.state.showModel} title="添加代金券"
                      centered
                      okText="保存" cancelText="取消"
                      onOk={() => this.okBtnClick}
                      onCancel={() => this.cancelClick}
>
```

I use ANTD's modal to make it vertically centered, but I was wrongly told that centered does not exist and attribute 1.

Comment: What is the version you are using? `centered` is available only in 3.x as far as I can see.

Comment: The latest version

Comment: I don't get an error.  Can you publish a repository that reproduces the problem?